# How to use Sumif within array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, sumifs

I'm trying to sum numbers that are in an array.
[image: Chart]

I get the attached error message.
[image: Error]

What is the syntax for using Sumif within an array?

```vb
Sub SumNumbers()

    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    Dim iMax As Long
    iMax = UBound(arr, 1)
    
    Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range(arr(1, 1), arr(iMax, 1)), "A", Range(arr(1, 2), arr(iMax, 2)))
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot build a range from the array values! Do you know what an array really is? Do you name a range as an array?

Comment: Clear! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

`SumIf` function works on ranges... At least its first parameter must be a range.

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub testSumif()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rngB As Range, rngC As Range, lastRow As Long

 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
 lastRow = sh.Range("B" & sh.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 Set rngB = sh.Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
 Set rngC = sh.Range("C2:C" & lastRow)

 Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.SumIf(rngB, "A", rngC)
End Sub
```

If you insist to use the `CurrentRegion`, try the next code, please:

```
Sub testSumifBis()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, rngB As Range, rngC As Range

 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need

 Set rng = sh.Range("B2").CurrentRegion
 Set rngB = rng.Columns(1)
 Set rngC = rng.Columns(2)

 Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.SumIf(rngB, "A", rngC)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Sumif vs Loop vs Match'n'Loop

- I would use the first solution.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub sumIfRange()
    
    Dim rg As Range
    ' Define Current Region range.
    Set rg = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    ' Only use data from 'A2' to 'Bwhatever' (no headers).
    Set rg = rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    
    Dim Result As Double
    Result = Application.SumIf(rg.Columns(1), "A", rg.Columns(2))
    
    Debug.Print Result
    
End Sub

Sub sumIfLoop()
    
    Dim rg As Range
    ' Define Current Region range.
    Set rg = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    ' Only use data from 'A2' to 'Bwhatever' (no headers).
    Set rg = rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    ' Only now write to array.
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rg.Resize(, 2).Value
    
    Dim Result As Double
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        If Not IsError(Data(i, 1)) Then
            If Data(i, 1) = "A" Then
                If IsNumeric(Data(i, 2)) Then
                    Result = Result + Data(i, 2)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
    Debug.Print Result
    
End Sub

Sub sumIfMatchLoop()
    
    Dim rg As Range
    ' Define Current Region range.
    Set rg = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    ' Only use data from 'A2' to 'Bwhatever' (no headers).
    Set rg = rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    ' Only now write to arrays.
    Dim lData As Variant: lData = rg.Columns(1).Value
    Dim rData As Variant: rData = rg.Columns(2).Value
    
    Dim mData As Variant: mData = Application.Match(lData, Array("A"), 0)
    Erase lData
    
    Dim Result As Double
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(mData)
        If IsNumeric(mData(i, 1)) Then
            Result = Result + rData(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    
    Debug.Print Result
    
End Sub
```